# How to skip existing files when copying local file system files to blob with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I've set up a pipeline that lifts large amount of files from on-prem to blob storage. Is there a way to have a scheduled pipeline that ignores previously uploaded files? Ideally it would work based on last modified time file property.

One of the option I'm thinking of is to have this pipeline set to OneTime and kick it off only when I need to sync files but there are two problems here:

- I want this pipeline not to involve manual activity such as executing jobs or moving files to time sliced folders
- It will still lift plenty of GB of data

What are the proper patterns to do that?

Comment: did you get anywhere on this in the end? I have a similar problem at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

With ADF V2, you could use [get Metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to get the lastModifed property to achieve this. You could then chain an if activity to check the lastModfied Time.